# PowerShell Sort-Object always returns System.Object[]

Tags: sorting, powershell

I have created a `List<string>` in PowerShell and want to sort this list using a script block with the code below:

```
$AssemblyNames = New-Object "System.Collections.Generic.List[string]"
$AssemblyNames.Add("PersonService.BizTalk.dll")
$AssemblyNames.Add("PersonService.BizTalk.Schemas.dll")
$SortedAssemblyNames = $AssemblyNames | Sort-Object { if ($_.ToLower().Contains("schema")) { 0 } else { 1 } }
$SortedAssemblyNames
```

which outputs:

```
PersonService.BizTalk.Schemas.dll
PersonService.BizTalk.dll
```

All fine, but I want to remove some elements later in processing these elements using:

```
$SortedAssemblyNames.Remove($SortedAssemblyNames.Item($i))
```

This produces the error

> Exception calling "Remove" with "1" argument(s): "Collection was of a fixed size.

So I checked the type of the `$SortedAssemblyNames` variable and I get `System.Object[]`. And this is strange as the `Sort-Object` documentation states:

> **Outputs**
>
> The output type is the type of the objects that the cmdlet
>   emits.

And in my opinion, this should be `System.String[]`. Am I wrong or is there a way to specify the output type of the `Sort-Object` cmdlet?

My current workaround is to loop through this collection and add it to a new `List<string>` but I think there should be a better solution as I need to modify the collection later and arrays are a pain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is how pipeline works:

- `Sort-Object` does not see your list. Your list enumerated by PowerShell and each individual item passed to `Sort-Object`.
- `Sort-Object` does not return array. `Sort-Object` write each individual item to the pipeline. PowerShell sees, that pipeline return more than one item and pack them into array.
- When PowerShell need to pack multiple pipeline results into array, it always create `System.Object[]` array. It does not try to find common most derived element type of array.

Comment: I agree it does not see the list. That's why I expected the output to be of type `System.String[]` as the type of each individual object is `System.String`. But maybe this is a documentation issue (or I don't understand it correctly).

Comment: @Scoregraphic Do you expect that PowerShell will check type of each returned item and create array with common most derived type as element type? And, BTW, returned items likely would be wrapped in `PSObject`, so it can not be `System.String[]`.

Comment: Not each item, but the first one and uses this type information to create the output type. As I'm writing this, I see that this would generate issues if you input objects out of a `List<object>`. Nevertheless is the documentation missleading.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what @PetSerAl said, this should work;

```
$AssemblyNames | Sort-Object { if ($_.ToLower().Contains("schema")) { 0 } else { 1 } } -OutVariable SortedAssemblyNames
$SortedAssemblyNames.Remove($SortedAssemblyNames.Item($i))
```

If it's implemented in a different way than you show here you might have to use `-OutVariable +SortedAssemblyNames` in order to not overwrite values (the + infront of the variable name).